# Scanning data for ordered node identifiers

Tags: perl

Consider this data:

```
12 45 64  
12 45 76  
12 37 39 87
12 67 90  
12 39 60
```

In this example there are just ten different numbers. If I have a large amount of data, how can I calculate it in Perl?

I have a link from 12 to 45, from 45 to 64, but not from 12 to 64.

We don't have a route from 45 to 12, so the neighbourhood of 12 is 4 (45, 37, 67, 39), and for 39 is 2 (87, 60)

How can I count the neighbourhood for all values in this data?

**Edit**

Another requirement is that we want to ignore any value that is directed to itself. For example, consider we have this file:

```
1 4 3
1 2 2
2 6 7
```

In this example, the neighbourhood of 1 must be (4, 2)

The neighbourhood of 4 must be 3

The neighbourhood of 2 must be 6 (and not 2)

I mean we must remove the matching and repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`Graph::Directed`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Graph%3a%3aDirected) module:

```
use Graph::Directed qw( );

my $graph = Graph::Directed->new();
while (<>) {
   my @points = split;
   $graph->add_edge(@points[$_-1, $_])
      for 1..$#points;
}

for my $vertex ($graph->vertices()) {
   my @successors = grep $_ != $vertex, $graph->successors($vertex);
   print("$vertex has ".@successors." successors: @successors\n");
}
```

Input:

```
1 4 3
1 2 2
2 6 7
```

Output:

```
6 has 1 successors: 7
4 has 1 successors: 3
2 has 1 successors: 6
1 has 2 successors: 4 2
3 has 0 successors:
7 has 0 successors:
```

Comment: You have correctly built a directed graph, but your code ignores its directedness. The OP clearly says *the neighbourhood of ... 39 is 2 (87, 60)*. I think you meant to call the `successors` method.

Comment: @Borodin, doh! Thanks, fixed. (I had only verified 12, which gave the right answer with `->neighbours`.)

Comment: Fixed so X is not returned as a neighbour of X.

Comment: The `grep` shouldn't be necessary. It makes no difference that I can see when applied to this data set. It would also make nonsense of the `is_successorless_vertex` test if every vertex were a successor of itself.

Comment: @Borodin, The responses to each of your sentences are: 1) Go reread the question because it is necessary (as it should be). 2) So what. 3) Noone said they were.

Comment: I suggest that your sample data should demonstrate the changes you have made to your code.

Comment: I can't fathom your change in attitude within the same comment stream, but I am sorry to have offended you. Please let's remember that Stack Overflow is a forum where we can learn from other programmers and encourage them in turn.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $data = <<'END_DATA';
12 45 64 
12 45 76 
12 37 39 87 
12 67 90 
12 39 60
END_DATA

my @lines = split/\n+/, $data;

# map number the list of numbers following it in the sequence 
my %neighborhoods = (); 
for my $line ( @lines ) { 
    my @nums = split m/\s+/,$line;
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#nums - 1 ) { 
        $neighborhoods{$nums[$i]}{$nums[$i+1]} = 1; 
    }
} 

foreach my $num ( sort keys %neighborhoods ) { 
   print "num [$num] neighboorhood (" . 
         ( join "-", keys %{$neighborhoods{$num}} ) . 
         ") count [" . ( scalar keys %{$neighborhoods{$num}} ) . 
         "]\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
num [12] neighboorhood (67-39-37-45) count [4]   
num [37] neighboorhood (39) count [1]
num [39] neighboorhood (60-87) count [2]
num [45] neighboorhood (64-76) count [2]
num [67] neighboorhood (90) count [1]
```

Comment: You should really delete your answer and add another one if you need to make such major changes to the original. As it stands the comments are now irrelevant.

Comment: @Borodin, Comments can marked as addressed ("Fixed"), which may even lead to their deletion.

Comment: @ikegami: Please offer a link to details of this. Do you mean flagging a comment as obsolete?

Comment: tnx.if we want to not consider the number that is match with the orginal number, how can we do this with perl.

Comment: @ikegami: Please explain *Comments can marked as addressed ("Fixed")*

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to count the number of nodes in the neighbourhood of every node on the graph. I think this does what you want.

I have modified my code since you have explained that a vector from a node to itself should be ignored.

```
use v5.10;
use warnings;

my %routes;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @nodes = /\d+/g;
  $routes{$_} //= {} for @nodes;
  while (@nodes >= 2) {
    my ($from, $to) = @nodes;
    $routes{$from}{$to}++ unless $from == $to;
    shift @nodes;
  }
}

for my $key (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %routes) {
  my $val = $routes{$key};
  printf "%d - neighbourhood size %d",
      $key,
      scalar keys %$val;
  printf " (%s)", join ', ', keys %$val if %$val;
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
12 45 64  
12 45 76  
12 37 39 87  
12 67 90  
12 39 60
1 4 3
1 2 2
2 6 7
```

**output**

```
1 - neighbourhood size 2 (4, 2)
2 - neighbourhood size 1 (6)
3 - neighbourhood size 0
4 - neighbourhood size 1 (3)
6 - neighbourhood size 1 (7)
7 - neighbourhood size 0
12 - neighbourhood size 4 (67, 39, 37, 45)
37 - neighbourhood size 1 (39)
39 - neighbourhood size 2 (60, 87)
45 - neighbourhood size 2 (64, 76)
60 - neighbourhood size 0
64 - neighbourhood size 0
67 - neighbourhood size 1 (90)
76 - neighbourhood size 0
87 - neighbourhood size 0
90 - neighbourhood size 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( %hash, %seen );

while (<DATA>) {
    my @nums = split;

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#nums - 1 ) {
        push @{ $hash{ $nums[$i] } }, $nums[ $i + 1 ]
          if !$seen{ $nums[$i] }{ $nums[ $i + 1 ] }++;
    }
}

for my $num ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash ) {
    print "$num has " . @{ $hash{$num} } . " neighbor(s): @{$hash{$num}}\n";
}

__DATA__
12 45 64  
12 45 76  
12 37 39 87
12 67 90  
12 39 60
```

Output:

```
12 has 4 neighbor(s): 45 37 67 39
37 has 1 neighbor(s): 39
39 has 2 neighbor(s): 87 60
45 has 2 neighbor(s): 64 76
67 has 1 neighbor(s): 90
```

Comment: tnx.now if we want to not consider the number that matching with orginal number, how can we do that.for example.

Comment: this data is read from bgpdump.they are not a geraph.they are AS that have a path to each other